# Pythonでの画像保存時にノイズが発生する

Tags: python, linux, 画像, audio

Pythonのコードで音声からスペクトログラムを生成し、画像に保存しています。
Windows環境では通常通りの画像が生成されているにもかかわらず、Linux環境では添付画像のような白いノイズが発生してしまっています。

対象の音声ファイルはscpコマンドでコピーしたものになるので同じだと認識してます。

一応、Pythonのライブラリ関連の環境は合わせており、GPU関連の挙動なのか？その他の要因なのか思案しているのですが、このような経験がある方いましたら、対処法など教えていただけると助かります。

関連するライブラリはコチラにまとめました。

```py
from pydub import AudioSegment
import cv2
import soundfile as sf
from PIL import Image
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: まずは、生成の各段階でデーターをファイルに出力し、それを両環境で比較して、どの処理を行なった際に差が出るのか特定するのが良いと思います。

Comment: 経験が無くても回答しようとする人がそのまま試せるソースコード・テストデータ・動作環境・作業手順などの情報が質問にすべて記載されていれば、問題を再現・調査しても良いと考える人が出てくるかもしれません。こちらのヘルプ記事などを参考に質問記事を改善してみてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3765)